# How to do a Mapper and return Single<MyObject>?

Tags: java, rx-java

I was using a `mapper` for other object and that's a `List` and I could do something like :

```
return myResponse.getData().map(myMapper(it))
```

And it works, but now, I'm not returning a `List<Object>` I'm returning an `Object` but I want to map the object to another object as :

```
data class PersonResponse(val id: Int, val name: String, val surname: String, val age: Int, val street: String....)
```

So now I want a `PersonViewModel` that only contains the `name` and `surname` how can I do it? My method is :

```
fun execute() : Single<PersonViewModel> { return myResponse.getData() //this returns a Single<PersonResponse>}
```

How do I map this? Or it's not necessary to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just use map:

```
fun execute() : Single<PersonViewModel> { 
    return myResponse.getData()
        .map { PersonViewModel(it.name, it.surname) }
}
```

or if you have a mapper from PersonResponse to PersonViewModel:

```
fun execute() : Single<PersonViewModel> { 
    return myResponse.getData()
        .map { personMapper.map(it) }
}
```